# External NLog.config without Visual Studio warnings or messages at the Error List window

Tags: xml, namespaces, configuration-files, nlog, xdt-transform

I use NLog as logging framework and try to figure out which settings are "optimal" for an external **transformation** configuration file (e.g. NLog.Debug.config).

On the [wiki page of the project](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-format), there are two options:

1. Inline (e.g inside Web.config or App.config)
2. Simplified xml in an external config file with **`<nlog>`** as **root element**

Here is an example configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="Warn" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger writeTo="Warn" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(writeTo)" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Despite the many namespaces, Visual Studio 2015 displays the following warning:
`The 'nlog' element is not declared.`

When I place the nlog part within a `<configuration>` element, this warning disappears, but a lot of "messages" appear, indicating that elements like name, target, async, and much more are unknown:
`Could not find schema information for the element 'target'.`

If I remove the suffix **nlog** from the namespace definition (`xmlns:nlog="...`) then the root element is accepted, but I see warnings for elements like target, xdt:Transform, xdt:Locator and so on:

```
The element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:target' is abstract or its type is abstract.
The 'autoreload' attribute is not declared.
The 'name' attribute is not declared.
...
```

I've already tried to move the namespaces to the different elements or giving every element or attribute the corresponding prefix, but nothing helped to let all warnings or messages disappear...

EDIT: Attributes are still marked with warnings like:
`The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Locator' attribute is not declared.`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to download the NLog.XSD and add it to the same directory.

The file is included in the NLog.Schema package ([link to Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema/))

**edit**: this works for me, where NLog is `xmlns` and not `xmlns:nlog`

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoreload="true">
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have already copied the file to the same directory. And additionally in VS under `XML - Schemas` the schema is marked as in use. This didn't help :-(

Comment: Updated the `xmlns`. Works for me

Comment: Updated xmlns, installed the newest NLog.Schema nuget package (4.3.11) into my project (my NLog.xsd got replaced with the new one) - the warnings for nodes like 'target' and attributes like 'name', 'xdt:Transform', 'xdt:Locator' are still there... :-(


`The element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:target' is abstract or its type is abstract.`
<br/>
`The 'name' attribute is not declared.`

Comment: sorry, not for me. plz see my answer above.